# How to align Material ui textfields in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am developing a `React js` application using `Material ui components`.

I am a 2 column `grid`, each column has 4 `textField`.

Some of those `textField` are weapped in `Autocomplete` component.

The problem is that they don't have the same styles thus they are not aligned facing each others.

Here is a screenshot of the result

[image]

As you can notice the problem in the second and third row of the left column.

Here is my code

```
<Grid container style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: 10 }}>
   <Grid item style={{ padding: 10 }} xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
       <TextField
        className={`${classes.textfield}  ${
          values.nameError && classes.inputError
        }`}
        onFocus={(e) => setValues({ ...values, nameError: false })}
        onChange={(e) => setValues({ ...values, name: e.target.value })}
        error={values.nameError}
        helperText={values.nameError ? t("Obligatoire") : ""}
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
        type="text"
        value={values.name}
        label={t("nomFR") + " *"}
        autoComplete="given-name"
      />
      //Same for the rest  
   </Grid>
   <Grid item style={{ padding: 10 }} xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
      <SelectInputWrapper>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <Autocomplete
            options={spaces}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
            renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
              <div className={classes.menuItem}>{option.label} </div>
            )}
            value={values.espace}
            disableClearable
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                error={values.espaceError}
                onFocus={(e) =>
                  setValues({ ...values, espaceError: false })
                }
                style={{ marginLeft: 3, marginRight: 3 }}
                margin="normal"
                value={""}
                label={t("Espace") + " *"}
              />
            )}
          />
          {values.espaceError && (
            <FormHelperText className={classes.helper} error={true}>
              {t("Obligatoire")}
            </FormHelperText>
          )}
        </FormControl>
      </SelectInputWrapper>
      //Same for the rest 
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Notice, I am not giving any margins or paddings.

Is there a solution please? I am stuck here for 2 days.

Comment: "I am not giving any margins or paddings" But you have style in TextField

Comment: It's empty, all styles are empty.

Comment: Lol "style={{ marginLeft: 3, marginRight: 3 }}" inside your TextField, for what have you this?

Comment: could you by chance create a code sandbox